# Variable for marking documents created each day, resetting every 24 hours

Tags: php, variables, reset, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF along with FPDI to create documents in PDF based on a template using a PHP form.

I need a way to ID them. The problem is - most of these documents were already created manually, thus having ID format already specified.

It's basically `Name-DD.MM.YYYY-X.pdf` and it can't change.

For example, Document-01.01.2014-2, where 2 means it's a second document issued that day.

Is there a way to do that automatically? I'm using a traditional `<form>` with `action` set to the PHP TCPDF script and it works flawlessly, but how to specify that if something was already generated today then do `$var = $var + 1` and then reset it at midnight?

Comment: use `glob()` to read the filenames into an array, then evaluate those

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the function [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php), in order to test if the base name is already generated or not.

If it is, simply create a loop and increment your $var to test iteratively your documents.

**Example:**

```
$baseName = "Name-DD.MM.YYYY";
$extension = ".pdf";
$i = 0;

while(1)
{
     if($i > 0)
         $testName = $baseName."-".$i.$extension;
     else
         $testName = $baseName.$extension;

     if(!file_exists($testName))
          break;

     $i++;
}

if($i > 0)
     $validName = $baseName."-".$i.$extension;
else
     $validName = $baseName.$extension;
```

Hoping my answer would help you,

Venom

Comment: That WOULD work (thank you, very much!) if only the files were actually stored on the server. Thing is - they are not, although I could tinker with that. Will definitely think about it!

Comment: Hmmm. Do you at least own the script for the document generation ?
If so, you could use a database (update a field everytime a document gets generated, and check the value of that field afterwards).